# Mongodb $lookup with condition in aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection called `article_parent` with documents like this:

```
    { "name": "name1", "group": 1 }
    { "name": "name2", "group": 1 }
    { "name": "name3", "group": 2 }
    { "name": "name4", "group": 3 }
    { "name": "name5", "group": 2 }
```

and I have other collection called `article` which store all my post

```
    {"parent_name": "name1", "value": "val1"}
    {"parent_name": "name2", "value": "val2"}
    {"parent_name": "name3", "value": "val3"}
    {"parent_name": "name4", "value": "val4"}
    {"parent_name": "name5", "value": "val5"}
```

I Want to get all articles that `article_parent.group` is 2 like this

```
    {"parent_name": "name3", "value": "val3", parent: { "name": "name3", "group": 2 }}
    {"parent_name": "name5", "value": "val5", parent: { "name": "name5", "group": 2 }}
```

I have this query :

```
db.article.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "article_parent",
        let: {
            name: "$parent_name"
        },
        pipeline: [
            { $match: { group: 2 } }
         ],
        as: "parent"}}
    ])
```

but the query not found any article

Where is my query wrong?

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: So what is the condition you need for finding `group=2`?. For eg : join the table when `parent_name = name3`

Comment: I edited my question to see the result I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have tried is appreciated. You tried to use [uncorrelated-sub-queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries). So when you use a variable inside pipeline which you defined inside `let`, you need to use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/). The problem you have done was, you didn't join both collections by one particular field.

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "article_parent",
      let: {
        pname: "$parent_name"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$name",
                "$$pname"
              ]
            },
            group: 2
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "parent"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      parent: {
        $ne: []
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xsD14v4qVMG)